# filename downloaded by wget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wget

I'm working in a Rails controller. I call a `wget` command `system(wget ...)`, and I want a variable that indicates the filename of the downloaded file.

For instance, for `wget google.com`, or `wget www.google.com`, or `wget www.google.com/`, or `wget http://www.google.com`, the returned name should be `index.html`.

For `example.com/firstpage.html`, the return name should be `firstpage.html`.

As you can see, I can't simply just strip the name after the last backslash. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can do it!

Process the string you get with regex to find everyting after the last /

```
@url= 'http://example.com/firstpage.html'
@file = @url.scan(/[^\/]*$/i)

puts @file  #firstpage.html
```

This regex also handles multiple forwards slashes so it can work with long urls too.

[**codepad example**](http://codepad.org/Khi1Sy3Y) and a good place to **[test your ruby regex](http://rubular.com/r/34gYgG6SZa)**

Comment: Lyuben Todorov, thanks for your answer. However, as I pointed out, I don't think regex alone suffices to do this (see my examples.)